# I get a 'No module named 'alpha_vantage'' error when i try importing alpha_vantage on Spyder

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, spyder

I just installed **alpha_vantage** using pip and tried it on IDLE but I'm more used to working on Spyder so when I tried importing it there, I got the **No module named 'alpha_vantage'**.

I thought the problem was that i used pip instead of conda but when I tried 'conda install alpha_vantage' I got a **PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: alpha_vantage**

Comment: In which environment did you install the module and in which environment is spyder running? It could be that it's installed in a different env than in which your spyder is running

Comment: @Junkrat I don't know if i have ever created an environment. I just installed anaconda and then spyder from the anaconda navigator and that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that that when you say that you installed it with pip, you mean from your systems default command line.
So, type the following command.
(for windows cmd)

```
where python
```

Do the same in spyder. The path output should match if not there is your problem.
(for unix)

```
which python
```

Comment: What am i supposed find when i use **where python** command. 
It showed **C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe**.
I didn't know how to exactly use the same command for spyder

Comment: Do you know shell your spyder is using? Linux, cmd, powershell?

Comment: Try "where python" and "which python" and see if it works.

Comment: i didn't work for spyder for some reason. When i tried **where spyder** from **C:\Users\Adam>**, it shows **INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).**

Comment: Sorry not explaining it well enough. Try "where python" from within spyder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222987/discussion-between-imgnome-and-bforce).

Answer (score 0):

First all, to use conda you need: conda activate .
To know conda env name: conda env list
When you stay in env conda : pip install alpha_vantage

Comment: I used conda env list and it just showed base environment and i'm pretty sure that's what Spyder is using